# Installing assembly into GAC after update?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, plugins, gac

How do I go about updating the assembly in the GAC after I change the code in my plugin?

I have a Class Library which I created in VS2010 following this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695782.aspx and it all works fine. But now I want to make a change to the code, how do I rebuild the project so the change is updated/reflected?

I tried building the project again, and adding to the GAC but now if I run the plugin I still have the same behavior from the first upload/install...

How do I update the GAC assembly after changing the code? I just dragged the new .dll in and also tried using the cmd prompt for VS2010 but still no change is reflected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dragging the new DLL into the GAC folders will not update the code in the GAC, you need to register the new DLL. You can use `gacutil` to manipulate the GAC. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx)

```
gacutil -i YourDLL.dll
```

Adding the `-i` flag tells the `gacutil` command that you want to install a new dll to the GAC.

You could also create a Visual Studio Installer project that will run as an installer and install your new code into the GAC. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/19x10e5c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: exactly what I did but its not taking effect...as in my code change is not reflected, could it be cached in my crm application maybe?

Comment: Make sure your application using the DLL is referencing the DLL from the GAC, and not referencing the project that is building the DLL that you want in the GAC. You could always try a Clean/Rebuild to clear any cache your application may be holding onto.

Comment: Did you get your problem figured out?